# Calculating average for selected columns from a form based query in access db

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to calculate an average from selected columns from a table.
For example i have a table in which 52 columns are there for each week of a year. now i want to calculate avg for current week to week 42 . range will be given from a form.

please help in sorting this problem out.

Comment: Your problem is that you use a table like a spreadsheet which it is not. You will have to study _normalisation_ of a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

Gustav is right, you do not have your tables set up correctly but this is still possible if you UNION your 52 weeks together like the example below which works from a table called data and has an ID column and a column for every week:

```
SELECT ID, count(ID) as count, Sum(stat) AS Total, sum(stat)/count(id) as average 

 FROM (

 SELECT Data.ID, Data.[Week 1] as stat
 FROM Data

 UNION ALL SELECT Data.ID, Data.[Week 2] as stat
 FROM Data

 UNION ALL SELECT Data.ID, Data.[Week 3] as stat
 FROM Data

 \\...add further unions here as required

 )      GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Thank you guys, i will try UNION to work this out and let you know.